# Exception class fails with recursive function

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, recursion, throw

I have an exception class called Exception, and I'm invoking a recursive function which gets called approximately 200 times while looping through a map. RecursiveFunction() is part of a class that contains a parameters map (which maps a string to a class param). The class param contains a min, a max, and number of steps between min and max, so that a set of functions can be run with each parameter set. RecursiveFunction() therefore loops through the map to run a set of functions given the 'current' parameters.

```
bool RecursiveFunction(map<string,param>::iterator current) {
   map<string,param>::iterator last = parameters.end();
   last--;
   if( current == last )
       return true;
   else {
       // Do some things
       if(something_wrong)
           throw Exception("RecursiveFunction()","Something went wrong");
       ++current;
       RecursiveFunction(current);
   }
}
```

The code above fails after about 120 recursive calls. It seems to be a memory issue, because most of the time it fails on the line:

```
last--;
```

The weird thing is that the code runs smoothly in both of the following cases:

```
bool RecursiveFunction(map<string,param>::iterator current) {
    ...
    if(something_wrong)
        throw "";
    ...
   }
```

or

```
bool RecursiveFunction(map<string,param>::iterator current) {
    ...
    if(something_wrong) {
        Exception exc = Exception("RecursiveFunction()","Something went wrong");
        ThrowException(exc); //ThrowException() { throw exc; }
    }
    ...
   }
```

The code isn't hitting the 'throw' so the Exception is not being constructed or copied (confirmed with breakpoints). Why would the existence of a class affect the outcome of a function, if that class isn't getting instantiated in the function?

EDIT:

I was able to reproduce this using a complete example (with Visual Studio 2010):

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Exception: public std::exception {
private:
    char        gsCallPath[1001];
    char        gsError[1001];
public:
    Exception(const char* sErrorCallPath, const char* sThrownError)
    {
       strcpy(gsError,sThrownError);
       strcpy(gsCallPath,sErrorCallPath);
    }
    ~Exception() {
    }
};

bool RecursiveFunction(int n);

int main() {
    RecursiveFunction(500);
}

bool RecursiveFunction(int n) {

    cout << n << '\n';

    if (n == 0)
        return true;
    else {
        if(false) {
            throw Exception("","");
            //throw "";
        }
        else
        {
            RecursiveFunction( n-1 );
        }
    }
}
```

The run crashed with a Stack Overflow exception. Replacing `throw Exception("","");` with `throw "";` allowed the program to run to completion. Note: the size of the Exception class had an impact on how big n needed to be in order to overflow. Thanks @catscradle and @Yakk for your comments.

Comment: It is unclear in the code what `parameters` is, how the function is called, what `// Do some things` does or when `something_wrong` will be `true`. As it is, it is impossible to answer the question.

Comment: In what way does it "fail"? (Most likely, the recursion is causing a stack overflow; luckily, it should be trivial to change it to use iteration instead, unless your actual code is very different to what you've posted).

Comment: Parameters are input to the function. something_wrong is true if some combination of parameters is incorrect, e.g. parameters["population_output_min_age"] < parameters["START_YEAR"]. This is irrelevant, since something_wrong is not evaluating to true.

Comment: This function has been working properly. The inclusion of the Exception class is making it fail. I'm wondering if there is something about the way throw is set up when C++ compiles that changes the make-up of the function. I'm not concerned with the recursive function.

Comment: @user1582665 no, `current` is the input to the function.  What is the symbol `parameters` and where does it come from?  http://sscce.org/ please.  "It worked before, and some innocuous change made it break" usually means you are invoking undefined behavior at some point.

Comment: Given your problem statement, it seems plausible that different versions of the exception give rise to different-sized stack frames, and that could plausibly cause the overflow. If that's the case, simplifying your code too much might simply make the problem disappear, although frankly I'm surprised the compiler can't flatten tail-call recursion.

Comment: @Yakk I should have been more clear. I've edited the question give more details about the param class and parameters map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <exception>
void f() {
    if (false) {
        throw "";
        //throw std::exception();
    }
    return f();
}
int main() {
    f();
}
```

Looking at the assembly, it seems that the function reserves stack space for the exception object and it doesn't matter if it gets thrown or not. So in case of `""` this function reserves 204 bytes(`sub esp, 0CCh`) and in case of `std::exception` it's `sub esp, 0D4h`, i.e. 8 bytes more, which is `sizeof(std::exception) - sizeof(char*)`.

Comment: Thanks. I've added an example that proves I can't use the Exception class within the recursive function because it gets reserved regardless of whether or not it's called. Using the ThrowException function seems to be the best solution for this.

Comment: @user1582665 Dunno about best. Are you sure that your recursion won't go deeper someday? I think you should come up with an iterative algorithm.

Comment: "best" was I guess a relative statement. I'll reconsider the recursion. Thanks again.